# How to stop GIF animations on Google Slides' slides preview

Tags: google-slides, animations

When using GIF animations on Google Slide, it keeps showing the slides preview with the GIFs in an infinite loop.

It's very annoying and attracting attention, is there any reason stopping it from being looped just in the slides preview column?

[image]